# Erro java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Quando executo .jar

Tags: java, netbeans, compilação

Estou a desenvolver na IDE Netbeans, quando executo pela IDE tudo funciona bem mas quando realizo o `clean and build` e crio o .jar ao executar lança me esta exceção:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei compilar package por package mas mesmo assim não funcionou.

Alguma sugestão para corrigir este problema?

**Edição** 
esta é a classe que o erro diz que falta, já verifiquei e o ficheiro .class está no jar, Será que tem algum erro que o compilador não consegue apanhar?

```
package gui.Admin;

import Models.Loteestado;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;


public class LoteEstadoTableModelTESTE  extends AbstractTableModel{
    private List<Loteestado> lotes;

    private String[] colunas = new String[] {
            "lote","ok|nok","Produto","Qtd Total", "Qtd","Progresso"};


    public LoteEstadoTableModelTESTE() {
        lotes = new ArrayList<Loteestado>();

    }

    public LoteEstadoTableModelTESTE(List<Loteestado> lote) {
        lotes = new ArrayList<Loteestado>(lote);
        }



    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {

        return colunas.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {

        return lotes.size();
    }


    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {

        return colunas[columnIndex];
    };


    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {

        switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0: 
                    return String.class;
                case 1: // RETURN OK OU NOK.
                    return String.class;                    
                case 2: //PRODUTO
                    return String.class;
                case 3: // MAX
                    return Integer.class;
                case 4: // REALIZADO
                    return Integer.class;
                case 5: // progress bar
                    return Integer.class;


        default:
            // Se o índice da coluna não for válido, lança um
            // IndexOutOfBoundsException (Exceção de índice fora dos limites).
            // Não foi necessário verificar se o índice da linha é inválido,
            // pois o próprio ArrayList lança a exceção caso seja inválido.
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("columnIndex out of bounds");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

        Loteestado lote = lotes.get(rowIndex);


        switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            return lote.getLinha();
                case 1: //Primeira coluna é o nome.
                { String estado="";
                    if (lote.getQtdrealizada() > 10 && lote.getQtdrealizada() <= lote.getQtdtotal() / 2 && lote.getAlrinicio() == false)
            estado="NOK"; 
                    else if (lote.getQtdrealizada() > 10 && lote.getQtdrealizada() >= lote.getQtdtotal() / 2 && lote.getAlrfim() == false)
                        estado="NOK"; 
                    else estado="OK"; 

                    return estado;
                }
                case 2: // Primeira coluna é o nome.
            return lote.getProduto().getNoproduto();                     
        case 3: // Segunda coluna qtd realizada.
            return lote.getQtdtotal();
                case 4: // Segunda coluna é a qtd total.
            return lote.getQtdrealizada();
                case 5: // Segunda coluna é a qtd total.
            if(lote.getQtdtotal() != 0) return ((lote.getQtdrealizada() * 100) /lote.getQtdtotal());
                        else return 0;


                default:
            // Se o índice da coluna não for válido, lança um
            // IndexOutOfBoundsException (Exceção de índice fora dos limites).
            // Não foi necessário verificar se o índice da linha é inválido,
            // pois o próprio ArrayList lança a exceção caso seja inválido.
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("columnIndex out of bounds");
        }
    }



    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            Loteestado lote = lotes.get(rowIndex);
            if (columnIndex == 0) {
                lote.setLinha(aValue.toString());
            }
            if (columnIndex == 2) {
                lote.getProduto().setNoproduto(aValue.toString());
            }
            if (columnIndex == 3) {
                lote.setQtdtotal((int)aValue);
            }
            if (columnIndex == 4) {
                lote.setQtdrealizada((int)aValue);
            }



        };


    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return false;
    }




    public Loteestado getlinha(int indiceLinha) {
        return lotes.get(indiceLinha);
    }


    //    public void ActuaLinha(){
//                linhas.set(removeLinha(indiceLinha), null)

  //      }

    public void addLinha(Loteestado linha) {
        // Adiciona o registro.
        lotes.add(linha);

        int ultimoIndice = getRowCount() - 1;

        fireTableRowsInserted(ultimoIndice, ultimoIndice);
    }


    public void removeLinha(int indiceLinha) {

        lotes.remove(indiceLinha);


        fireTableRowsDeleted(indiceLinha, indiceLinha);
    }

        public boolean IsContem(Loteestado lot){

           for(Loteestado lote:lotes)
           if(lote.getProduto().equals(lot.getProduto()))return true;

           return false;

        }


    public void addListaDeLinhas(List<Loteestado> linhass) {

        int tamanhoAntigo = getRowCount();

        lotes.addAll(linhass);


        fireTableRowsInserted(tamanhoAntigo, getRowCount() - 1);
    }

        public boolean procuraNome(Loteestado lote){

            if(lotes.contains(lote)){return true;}
            else {return false;}
        }

        public void actualizaLista(Loteestado lote){
            if(lotes.contains(lote)){
                for(Loteestado item : lotes){
                    if(item.equals(lote)) {lotes.set(lotes.indexOf(item), lote); fireTableRowsUpdated(lotes.indexOf(item), lotes.indexOf(item));}
                }

            }
            else {lotes.add(lote); fireTableRowsUpdated(lotes.indexOf(lote), lotes.indexOf(lote));}




        }

    public void limpar() {

        lotes.clear();

        fireTableDataChanged();
        }


    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return lotes.isEmpty();
    }

}
```

Depois disso faço o uso normal dela:

```
jTblLinhasOnline.setModel(new LoteEstadoTableModelTESTE());
```

Aguem me consegue ajudar?

**Edição 2**

Copiei a classe para a classe `SoftwareGui` e funcionou, contudo se alguém souber a outra resolução preferia...

Comment: A classe `gui.tabelasLinhasonline.TesteLoteEstadoTableModel` existe? Está em algum JAR no classpath? Há algum erro de capitalização nela (esse L maiúsculo no nome do pacote me é suspeito)? Há algum erro de digitação nela (ex: deveria ser `Linha` ao invés de `Linhas`)?

Comment: @Victor no .jar que cria está lá essa classe, numa das tentativas de resolver o problema alterei o nome dela "TesteLoteEstadoTableModel" e vi que tinha um problema porque a palavra iniciava com letra minúscula, corrigi mas voltou a dar o mesmo erro... Contudo vou voltar a analisar essa possibilidade de erro de digitação

Comment: @Victor já alterei o nome, já alterei a diretoria dessa classe, já a copiei para uma nova classe com um nome diferente mas mesmo assim não estou a conseguir, não percebo porquê

Comment: Poste então o código do `GUI.SoftwareGUI` para ver se ela não faz nada de muito bizarro. Mas antes disso, vale a pena recompilar tudo do zero com um ambiente limpo.

Comment: @Victor "ambiente limpo" ao que se refere? criar um novo projeto e mandar este lá para dentro? Estou agora a pensar em outro possível problema eu comecei este projeto no netbeans 7 e agora estou trabalho no 8 em outro computador será pode ser disso?

Comment: Ambiente limpo quer dizer apagar todos os ".class" e todos os jars que são gerados pelo processo de compilação. Enfim ter apenas os códigos-fontes, os JARs do classpath e outros arquivos necessários que o compilador não use (como `pom.xml`, figuras, arquivos de configuração, etc).

Comment: Tudo corre mal, no netbenas tem uma opção que diz "inspecionar" só que para isso tive de instalar um "plugin" agora o netbeans não inicia grande mer***... esses ficheiros .class estão na pasta "build" certo?

Comment: Só dar um "Clean and Build" deveria ser suficiente. Não precisa de plugin nenhum para isso. Mas sim, eles devem estar na pasta `build`. E os JARs gerados na pasta `dist`. Delete tudo que estiver dentro destas pastas, deixando-as vazias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neste caso o problema estava na cache do netbeans.

Este é o diretório:

> C:\Users\jsan7os1991\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.0

Devem de proceder a limpeza de todos os ficheiros.

Answer (score 3):

A exceção [`NoClassDefFoundError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) é lançada quando a [JVM](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A1quina_virtual_Java) não é capaz de encontrar uma determinada classe em tempo de execução que estava disponível em tempo de compilação, exemplificando, se um método ou qualquer membro estático de uma classe não estiver disponível em *runtime*, `NoClassDefFoundError` é lançado.

É importante entender que `NoClassDefFoundError` e [`ClassNotFoundException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html) são exceções distintas, essa última é lançada quando se tenta carregar uma classe através do nome, por meio dos métodos [`ForName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) da classe [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html), [`loadClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass%28java.lang.String%29) e [`findSystemClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#findSystemClass%28java.lang.String%29) da classe [`ClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html). Isso acontece quando nenhuma definição para o nome da classe fornecida foi encontrada.

> Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Esse erro geralmente é vinculado ao [**classpath**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) que pode não estar configurado ou referenciado de modo correto. Você chegou a verificar se esse problema sucedia ao especificar o *class path* usando a opção `-classpath` ou `-cp`?

Também pode ser provável que os dados de cache possam ter se corrompido devido a algum [Crash](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travamento) que a *IDE* sofreu, isso justifica claramente o comportamento estranho que o Netbeans teve segundo esse seu [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46982/erro-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundexception#comment94565_46982).

No [Bugzilla](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=194263) tem algo semelhante a essa situação, porém ocorre em outra versão(6.x), a solução encontrada foi a mesma que a sua, eliminar o cache.

Answer (score 0):

Olhando o consolo que você colou, o JRE está se queixando da seguinte classe:

```
gui.tabelaLinhasonline.TesteLoteEstadoTableModel
```

Porém, o código que você colou é da seguinte classe:

```
gui.Admin.LoteEstadoTableModelTESTE
```

Procure no seu código por ocorrências da primera class (a que lança `ClassNotFoundException`) e substitua pela segunda.

Comment: bem observado, mas esse não era o problema, os nomes são diferentes porque quando aconteceu o erro e o publiquei recebi a ajuda do victor a dizer para verificar se o nome estava correto ou senão havia algum problemas com as letras maiúsculas ou minúsculas, e na tentativa de verificar isso alterei os nomes, contudo não resolveu o problema, mas como estava sempre a apontar para essa classe decidi postar aqui não fosse as vezes estar a fazer alguma barbaridade com ela que o compilador não apanha-se.... Daí nomes diferente contudo obrigado pela tentativa de ajuda

Comment: Ok. Você criou uma innerclass? Você consegue reproduzir o erro anterior mas com o ambiente (código) atualizado?

Comment: Sim depois de ter criado a innerclass esse erro deixou de aparecer, mas apareceram outros iguais a este a apontar para outras classes, então depois de alguma pesquisa vi que era problema da cache do netbeans, quando a limpei tudo ficou resolvido...